# How to repair a 2003 Kia Sedona side mirror

Tags: kia

I've just bought used 2003 Kia Sedona.

The left side mirror accidentally hit a pole at my house, flipping the left side mirror backwards.

I pushed it back, and it looks normal but I can no longer adjust it electronically, the internal motor runs but cannot move the mirror.

Can I repair it myself?

Comment: You need to open the assembly up. What do you see in there? Is the gear broken? Or is it just not connecting with the teeth on the mirror mounting?

Comment: I will do it. I need time to open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you discover that the internal gearing is broken, you will most likely need to purchase a new one and replace the damaged mirror.

[http://www.amazon.com/TYC-8140032-Sedona-Non-Heated-Replacement/dp/B0041TUBWS/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1351970333&sr=8-4&keywords=2003+kia+sedona+side+mirror](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0041TUBWS)

Comment: Thanks. I've opened it. Nothing broken, except the plastic cover has been bent that prevent the flipping. I've repaired it myself and everything is fine now.